# SelectItems with list of string in jsf

Tags: jsf-2

I have list of String like this in managed bean :

```
 List<String> roleList = Arrays.asList("MANAGER", "ADMIN", "USER");
```

I want to use it in a selectOneMenu like this :

```
        <f:selectItems itemLabel="#{userMB.roleList}" ....}"/>
  </h:selectOneMenu>
```

both value and lable Iwant to be the same

what I must do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<f:selectItems value="#{userMB.roleList}" var="role" 
               itemLabel="#{role}" itemValue="#{role}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

We can write a short code as below.

```
<f:selectItems value="#{userMB.roleList}"/>
```